# How to start the app with the UIViewController specified? not with the first

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I've got view-based application, I don't want to start with the first standart view, how should I start with another view?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the *MainWindow.xib* file to add your view controller as the subview of the main window. Or, you can do it by code like this, in *applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:* method.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    YourViewController *vc = [[YourViewController alloc] init];

     // You can add it as subView
    [self.window addSubview:vc]; 

    // Or, add it as rootViewController (available from iOS 4.0)
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;

    [vc release];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the view controller you would like to load to the root view controller
Place this in your app delegate with viewcontroller being the name of the view controller you would like to load

```
window.rootViewController = viewController
```

Answer (score 0):

in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOption: just declare you new viewController and addIt

```
SomeViewController *svc = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithFrame: ... ];
[self.window addSubview:avc.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to change it in the appdelegate like this...

```
 viewController=[[sampleFirst alloc]init];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

B4 tat u need to declare the  sampleFirst viewcontroller class as a property in the appdelegate header file like this..(after declaring the viewcontroller object for sampleFirst viewcontroller class)

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet sampleFirst *viewController;
```